# How to left-join and include nulls?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to join 2 tables together.

**Table A** = Customers who bought a product in 2019.

**Table B** = Customers that bought a product and are active at month 12 and all the months active after (e.g active at month 13, month 14 etc.)

Table B currently excludes people that bought a product in 2019, as they cannot have been active for 12m since buying.

However, I want to include Table A customers in Table B, simply for the purpose of my base of customers. Any calculations can be represented as Null.

So my table should in the end look like:

```
Customer ID           Date        Month       Active
                (product bought)        
A                 2018-01-01       12           1  
A                 2018-01-01       13           1   
A                 2018-01-01       14           1   
B                 2019-01-01       Null         Null 
C                 2019-04-01       Null         Null
```

Whenever I try a left join, it doesn't seem to work. I was wondering what the best way to include these customers in to my table was?

Table A **currently** looks like

```
Customer ID           Date        Month       Active
                (product bought)        
B                 2019-01-01       1           1 
C                 2019-04-01       1           1
```

Month = 1 means they bought a product and were active. However since they haven't reached 12 months after the date (i.e 2020-01-01 or 2020-04-01), then they cannot be included in my base for Table B, therefore should have no data, hence should appear null in Table B. Although I solely need their ID's in the table for the sake of my base.

Thanks!
Manisha

Comment: Share the query you have so far

Comment: Please show the original data.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I've edited the question. Let me know if this is clearer! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `union all`:

```
select b.customerid, b.date, b.month, b.active
from b
union all
select a.customerid, a.date, null, null
from a;
```